# How to write text into textarea using python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, textarea, captcha

I have a code to solve a test captcha. A captcha solution token arrives, then with the code the display for entering the token opens, but no matter how I try, I can’t enter the token using the code below
https://2captcha.com/demo/hcaptcha
[image: image of capture form]

[image: image of capture form after attempted entry with the error "hCaptcha solved incorrectly, please try again."]

```
def Solver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(page_url)
    time.sleep(10)
    every_element = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, "h-captcha-response")

    for element in every_element:
        display_prop = element.value_of_css_property('display')
        if display_prop == 'none':
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", element)


    u1 = f"http://rucaptcha.com/in.php?key={API_KEY}&method=hcaptcha&sitekey={data_sitekey}&pageurl={page_url}&json=1&invisible=1"
    r1 = requests.get(u1)
    print(r1.json())
    rid = r1.json().get("request")
    u2 = f"https://rucaptcha.com/res.php?key={API_KEY}&sitekey={data_sitekey}&action=get&id={int(rid)}&json=1"
    time.sleep(5)
    while True:
        r2 = requests.get(u2)
        print(r2.json())
        if r2.json().get("status") == 1:
            form_token = r2.json().get("request")
            break
        time.sleep(5)
    write_token_js = f'document.getElementsByName("h-captcha-response").innerHTML"{form_token}";'
    time.sleep(5)
    submit_js = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#root > div > main > div > section > form > button._2iYm2u0v9LWjjsuiyfKsv4._1z3RdCK9ek3YQYwshGZNjf._3zBeuZ3zVV-s2YdppESngy._28oc7jlCOdc1KAtktSUZvQ")
    submit_js.click()
    driver.execute_script(write_token_js)
    time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Solver()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using this code:

```
write_token = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "h-captcha-response")
write_token.send_keys(f"{form_token}")
```